# How do i add nearest markers in google maps programmatically through json data

Tags: java, android

I am fairly new to stack and Android and in need of some help adding nearest markers through android code with JSON data, the lat and lon come through in the JSON. I have the store info displaying on the page I just do not know how to add markers to the map. Any help would be appreciated
my code is below:

```
package com.example.mdona.maptest;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.renderscript.Double3;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;

import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import static android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
import static android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
import static java.lang.Double.valueOf;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private static JsonNinja jninja = new JsonNinja();
    private static String API_KEY ="MDpmNWI1YTdkYS1lNDNhLTExZTgtOTE1Yy02ZjczZWQ0ZmIxM2M6dkJad1htQW56TUtNMWRDSzJISjZoVjU3bzFRNE9GREdHT1ZK";
    private ArrayList<String> address_final = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> storeLat = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> storeLon = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> city = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> telephone = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> quantity = new ArrayList<>();
    String product_id;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    LinearLayout NearestLocation;

    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    SupportMapFragment mapFrag;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
    FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);

        NearestLocation = findViewById(R.id.nearest_location);
}

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mFusedLocationClient != null) {
            mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(120000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(120000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
                mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
            else {
                checkLocationPermission();
            }
        }
        else {
            mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    LocationCallback mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            List<Location> locationList = locationResult.getLocations();
            if (locationList.size() > 0) {
                Location location = locationList.get(locationList.size() - 1);

                mLastLocation = location;
                if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
                    mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
                }

                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                markerOptions.position(latLng);
                markerOptions.title("Current Position");
                markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
                mCurrLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

                getLatitude();
                getLongitude();
                getUserStoreLocInv("311787", latitude, longitude);

                mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 11));
            }
        }
    };

    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
    private void checkLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Location Permission Needed")
                        .setMessage("This app needs the Location permission, please accept to use location functionality")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this,
                                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
                            }
                        })
                        .create()
                        .show();
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
                        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
        }
        return latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
        }
        return longitude;
    }

    public void getUserStoreLocInv(String product_id, double lat, double lon) {

        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
                client.addHeader("Authorization", API_KEY);
                client.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");

                client.get("http://lcboapi.com/stores?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon + "&product_id=" + product_id + "&per_page=5", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                    //====================================>>
                    //=========== SUCCESS =============>>
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                        Log.e("Success", "Yes!");

                String converted_string = new String(responseBody);
                jninja.NinjaParse(converted_string);

                ArrayList<String> names = jninja.GetNames();
                ArrayList<String> vals = jninja.GetVals();

                for (int i = 0; i < vals.size(); i++) {
                    if (names.get(i).equals("address_line_1")) {
                        address_final.add(vals.get(i).replace("\"",""));
                    }
                    if (names.get(i).equals("city")) {
                        city.add(vals.get(i).replace("\"",""));
                    }
                    if (names.get(i).equals("telephone")) {
                        telephone.add(vals.get(i).replace("\"",""));
                    }
                    if (names.get(i).equals("quantity")) {
                        quantity.add(vals.get(i));
                    }
                    if (names.get(i).equals("latitude")) {
                        storeLat.add(vals.get(i));
                    }
                    if (names.get(i).equals("longitude")) {
                        storeLon.add(vals.get(i));
                    }
                }
                CreateStoreAddress(address_final, city, telephone, quantity);
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                Log.e("Fail", "No!");
            }
        });
    }
            public void CreateStoreAddress(ArrayList<String> address_final, ArrayList<String> city, ArrayList<String> telephone,
                ArrayList<String> quantity)
            {
                Point size = new Point();
                getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
                int screenWidth = size.x;

                for (int i = 0; i < address_final.size(); i++) {

                    LinearLayout addressCompleteLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
                    LinearLayout addressLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
                    LinearLayout cityLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
                    LinearLayout telephoneLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
                    LinearLayout quantityLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

                    GradientDrawable border = new GradientDrawable();
                    border.setStroke(3, Color.BLACK);
                    border.setSize(screenWidth, 100);

                    TextView address = new TextView(this);
                    TextView city_loc = new TextView(this);
                    TextView phone = new TextView(this);
                    TextView amount = new TextView(this);

                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    params.setMargins(20,20,20,20);

                    addressCompleteLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
                    addressCompleteLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                    addressCompleteLayout.setBackground(border);
                    NearestLocation.addView(addressCompleteLayout);

                    addressLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
                    addressLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                    addressCompleteLayout.addView(addressLayout);

                    cityLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
                    cityLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                    addressCompleteLayout.addView(cityLayout);

                    telephoneLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
                    telephoneLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                    addressCompleteLayout.addView(telephoneLayout);

                    quantityLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
                    quantityLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                    addressCompleteLayout.addView(quantityLayout);

                    address.setLayoutParams(params);
                    address.setText("Address: " + address_final.get(i));
                    addressLayout.addView(address);

                    city_loc.setLayoutParams(params);
                    city_loc.setText("City: " + city.get(i));
                    cityLayout.addView(city_loc);

                    amount.setLayoutParams(params);
                    amount.setText("Quantity Available: " + quantity.get(i));
                    quantityLayout.addView(amount);

                    phone.setLayoutParams(params);
                    phone.setText("Phone #: " + telephone.get(i));
                    telephoneLayout.addView(phone);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a _lot_ of code with no explanation...

Comment: Yes. It would be better if you were to take out all the imports and explain the purpose of your code. It is a lot of code to read and understand.

Comment: Basically, people are asking for a [mcve] that describes your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you would do to create a marker is add the following to `onMapReady`:

```
final LatLng coordinates= new LatLng(35, 35);
Marker Options myMarker= new MarkerOptions().position(coordinates).title("Location").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
mGoogleMap.addMarker(myMarker);
```

This adds a marker on your map. Now, what you can do is replace the `35` with the coordinates from your json file. I hope this answers your question.